# Measuring WebGL efficency

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl2

I’m working on a ThreeJs project that requires some heavy-duty work done with in a fragment shader so I am looking for a way to use lower quality if the device can’t handle the work.
By pure accident I recently included an ‘uint’ uniform in my shader code and found it just would not run-on older devices. So, the availability of WebGL2 became an obvious and good switch.
The problem is that WebGL2 is a browser choice and some older devices with later software will still run it even if very badly.
Is there a quick test to determine WebGL efficiency so I can fall back to lower quality if needed.
Measuring FPS is not an option since even on a modern device it can take a few seconds for it to stabilize for a new page.

Comment: What do you mean by “WebGL 2 is a browser choice”? It’s available in every major browser nowadays: https://caniuse.com/webgl2

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I currently have limited devices for testing, one is an old Galaxy S4 that will only run Chrome 95 which doesn't support WebGL2 and that's fine since I can use that to fall back to lower quality graphics. Another is an old Mac Book Air that has Safari 13.1.2 which again doesn't support WebGL2 so I can use that to fallback. It also has Chrome 108 which does support WebGL2, but the because of devices age the GPU now struggles with the work load so I need another method to trigger the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general solution.
But in my particular situation I am using a very expensive SDF that is needed in both the Hi and Lo versions of the graphicsis. It is generated once and stored in a FBO, then used again multiple times as a texture.
Even on a desktop using a RTX 3060 Ti it takes more than 20mS to generate the texture, on the old S4 it's 320+ mS to generate.
They're not ideal metrics but with a bit tuning they should provide a way of guesstimating the GPU's capability and give a good indication of when to fall back to simpler graphics.
There will always be a cut off of what we support but being able to get the best from older devices is not a bad thing.

Comment: Doing a test if pretty much the only way to handle this. As an alternative to testing gpu speed you could test gpu memory size and, for example, if you can allocate 3GB then you are probably working with a decent device.